# Creating a Generic Sort function in Extension

Tags: swift, generics, extension-methods

I would like to know what I am doing wrong here. I would like not to use force casting but no matter what I try I do not seem able to.

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    func highestPriority<T: Equatable>( priority: [T]) -> T? {
        let sorted = sorted { lhs, rhs in
            guard let lhs = priority.firstIndex(of: lhs as! T),
                  let rhs = priority.firstIndex(of: rhs as! T) else {
                return false
            }
            return lhs < rhs
        }
        return sorted.first as? T
    }
}

public enum Jobs: String, Codable {
    case wash = "Wash"
    case dry = "Dry"
    case wax = "Wax"
}

let priorities: [Jobs] = [.wash, .dry, .wax]

let jobs: [Jobs] = [.wax, .wash, .dry]

let priority = jobs.highestPriority(priority: priorities)
```

Im refining from this which works, but I'm not understanding why changing collection to use self in Array is any different?

```
func highestPriority<T:Equatable>(_ collection: [T]?, priority: [T]) -> T? {
    let sorted = collection?.sorted { lhs, rhs in
        guard let lhs = priority.firstIndex(of: lhs),
              let rhs = priority.firstIndex(of: rhs) else {
            return false
        }
        return lhs < rhs
    }
    return sorted?.first
}

public enum Jobs: String, Codable {
    case wash = "Wash"
    case dry = "Dry"
    case wax = "Wax"
}

let priorities: [Jobs] = [.wash, .dry, .wax]

let jobs: [Jobs] = [.wax, .wash, .dry]

let priority = highestPriority(jobs, priority: priorities)
```

I have tried changing the generic constraint but I'm just stabbing in the dark :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of the types associated with `highestPriority` are the same as the type stored in the array, change `highestPriority` from being generic to being based on `Element`.

```swift
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func highestPriority(priority: [Element]) -> Element? {
        let sort = sorted { lhs, rhs in
            guard let lhs = priority.firstIndex(of: lhs),
                  let rhs = priority.firstIndex(of: rhs) else {
                return false
            }
            return lhs < rhs
        }

        return sort.first
    }
}
```

---

Here's a much simpler implementation:

```swift
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func highestPriority( priority: [Element]) -> Element? {
        return priority.first { contains($0) }
    }
}
```

---

If the array will have a lot of elements (and the elements are Hashable), it would likely be more efficient as:

```swift
extension Array where Element : Hashable {
    func highestPriority(priority: [Element]) -> Element? {
        let set = Set(self)
        return priority.first { set.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow thank you. looks so simple. I guess I was trying too hard to use generics.

Comment: @user3464381 or simply return `priority.first(where: Set(self).contains) `. I would also extend `Collection` instead of `Array` and change the method declaration to `func highestPriority(_ priority: [Element]) -> Element?` or `func highest(priority: [Element]) -> Element?` to adhere to Swift naming conventions.